# How to pass color through inline styles to animated div

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have this animation which is part of an react application. I need to pass the `color` dynamically (which I have to do through inline styles, currently its hard coded `black`). However, this breaks the animation. The black fill should start all the way from the left, and not in the middle. In fact, it is not animated at all. This works if I leave `background: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, transparent 0);` in the CSS file.

Working example

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
}

.filling {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 3px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, transparent 0);
    background-size: 200% 100%;
    background-position: right;
    animation: fill-div-with-color 8s 1s forwards;
}

@keyframes fill-div-with-color {
    100% { background-position: left;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="filling"/>
</div>
```

Not working example

```css
    .container {
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
    }

    .filling {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 3px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 30px;
        display: block;
        background-size: 200% 100%;
        background-position: right;
        animation: fill-div-with-color 8s 1s forwards;
    }

    @keyframes fill-div-with-color {
        100% { background-position: left;}
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="filling" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, transparent 0);"/>
    </div>
```

Why can't I pass the styles inline?

Comment: a) `style="linear-gradient(to...)"`- that is incomplete, you left out the `background:`, and b) your stylesheet applied this on the `.filling` element, whereas you set your inline style on `.element` instead.

Comment: @CBroe b) was a typo. Regarding a), the `black` in `linear-gradient(...` is the background-color?!

Comment: Yes, and? That doesn't change the fact that the _name_ of the CSS property that you want to set a value for there, is missing.

Comment: @CBroe Now I get what you are referring to. I edited my Q. That was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`background` is a [shorthand for several background properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background#constituent_properties), including `background-size` and `background-position`. Since you are using inline styles, your background styles in `.filling` are being overwritten. You can fix this by changing your inline styles from `background: linear...` to `background-image: linear...`

```css
    .container {
        position: relative;
        width: 500px;
    }

    .filling {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 3px;
        width: 500px;
        height: 30px;
        display: block;
        background-size: 200% 100%;
        background-position: right;
        animation: fill-div-with-color 8s 1s forwards;
    }

    @keyframes fill-div-with-color {
        100% { background-position: left;}
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="filling" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, transparent 0);"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: thanks. I assumed that the reason might be the one you are writing, but I was unsure how to work around it!

Comment: yeah, gradients can be tricky. [Linear gradients transform into images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient), and that's why we use the `background-image` property for them.